# Cohen'z dz, how to calculate the change score within group in R

Tags: r, statistics

I running a pre-post test/intervention design with two different groups. As such, I was looking at effect sizes (i.e., Cohen's D) as my measure of change when I realized this isn't an accurate reflection of the change score, thus need to be calculating Cohen's Dz. I've never done this before, and usually just rely on R packages to run Cohen's D, but cannot find the function nor a package that can run Cohen's Dz. Any advice of what packages to turn to and/or scripts?

Comment: As currently worded, your question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow ("Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.")

Comment: A quick search suggests `misty::cohens.d()`: "Cohen's d_z is computed when using weighted = TRUE, default" https://rdrr.io/cran/misty/man/cohens.d.html